# POST body cannot be created

Tags: java, spring, post

I'm working on the Spring application with Angular frontend. I'm trying to send a POST request to update data in the database but there is an exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
> construct instance of UpdateRecipesDTO

There is the DTO class that I receive from the frontend part:

```java
@Data
public class UpdateRecipesDTO {
    private String query;
    private String meal;
    private String dish;
    private String cuisine;
}
```

And it goes to the controller method

```
@PostMapping(value = "/recipe-update")
public int updateByAdmin(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody UpdateRecipesDTO updateRecipesDTO) {
    System.out.println("You're here");
}
```

Now the only that I want is a printed string but it doesn't print anything. I had tried to use `@AllArgsConstructor` Lombok annotation, but it didn't work. Writing AllArgsConstructor by myself didn't help also. So what should I do?

Comment: I think `UpdateRecipiesDTO` should contain empty constructor.

Comment: Could you show the JSON/XML you are attempting to POST?

Comment: As @bradley101 suggested, you could try adding '@NoArgsConstructor'

Comment: My opinion, the point of this problem is your request data (especially request body). Could you put it on the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.